# merger.xml modified with each new run

Tags: android

I am using one third party module (custom calendar) in app but every time when i run my app it modifies below file

**build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseAssets/merger.xml**

It cause me to push it again and again on my git repository. I used git ignore but it still modify the above file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your entire `build/` directory should be in `.gitignore`, let alone that file. So, what exactly is your concern?

Comment: /build  its already there. Is there any way to stop modifying that file instead of adding it to git ignore

Comment: Get rid of your module's `assets/` directory from all of it source sets. Then, get rid of every dependency that contains assets. If you look at the contents of the file, you should get an idea of where the assets are coming from.